# Replace the bad words /swearings from Firebase Cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to replace the bad words /swearings if a user made them in the comment. and I'm trying to do this from firebase cloud function:
the comment text is under the comment_key which is under the post_key

[image]

I'm using the code below in the firebase cloud function (which works if the "text" was directly under the {post_key} ). but when adding the {comment_key} wildcard the code doesn't work.

```js
exports.removeSwear = functions.database.ref('/post-comments/{post_key}/{comment_key}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

  const postData = snapshot.val();
  

  
  const new_text = noSwearWords(postData.text)
  return snapshot.ref.update({text: new_text});
  
});
function noSwearWords(text) {
return text.replace(/\bad|word\b/g, '****')}
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the "text" that is under the comment_key as in the above photo?

Comment: why are u using wildcard if the node is always going to be called comment_key and post_key?

Comment: the comment_key and the comment_key are push keys and they change for each comment. I created the picture to illustrate, but maybe it's confusing I'll change it.

Comment: what does console.log(postData) give you?

Comment: removeSwear
this is the postData: { text: 'word', uid: '3Tw4xE97z0cooB8xoeq7VuAH3oG2' }

Comment: so it is returning the text and uid what is the issue then, do you have a `text` with a value only `word`?

Comment: I tested again and it suddenly worked without changing the code, not sure why, but I've tested for hours before asking the question. much appreciated your reaction on the question @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    exports.removeSwear = functions.database.ref('/post-comments/{post_key}/{comment_key}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

      const postData = snapshot.val();
      

      
      const new_text = noSwearWords(postData.text)
      return snapshot.ref.update({text: new_text});
      
    });
    function noSwearWords(text) {
    return text.replace(/\bad|word\b/g, '****')}
```